# How to reinstall Ubuntu 14.04's default login screen

Tags: 14.04, login-screen, desktop-background

I was playing around with the different Window Managers and I ended up uninstalling the default login screen (I think) How can I reinstall that without reinstalling the whole distro?

Answer (score 0):

The default Ubuntu login screen is called `lightdm`. Chances are it's still installed, so you can just do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` to re-select it. If it isn't installed, just run `sudo apt-get install lightdm` and then the command above. If you want to uninstall the other login screen (really a display manager), write down the other choices that show up when you run the reconfigure command.

Comment: followed your dirrections but now when I get to the login screen all I get is the blank gray background. The desktop backgrounds of the  various users do not appear. How do I fix that?

Comment: Hmm. Enter a TTY (ctrl+alt+f1), log in and try `sudo apt-get install -f` and then `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`.

Comment: lightdm and not gdm?

Comment: Do you want to use `gdm`?